# Why do I get DMARC aggregate reports with no reported failures (G Suite + Amazon SES)?

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc

Domain: franzoni.eu

Such domain leverages G Suite (grandfathered free version) for receiving mail, but for various reasons (I prefer not to create users for M2M SMTP on G Suite, and I cannot use SMTP to send with aliased source addresses) I setup Amazon SES for sending e-mails; the domain is verified in Amazon SES, I added all the records for DKIM and SPF.

The strange issue is: I get DMARC aggregate reports whenever I send mail through Amazon SES. I have tried via Postfix from my servers and via Gmail (I setup a custom SMTP server on my personal gmail.com account, using a verified identity @franzoni.eu as an alias).

But **such reports show no failure**, and my DMARC **fo is set to 1**, which should mean to send a report iff an error in either SPF or DKIM was found. If I send an e-mail to gmail or other providers, I can find no failures in headers, either; dkim and spf are "pass" everywhere.

Sample aggregate report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>google.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
    <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>17723215002606464836</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1636675200</begin>
      <end>1636761599</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>franzoni.eu</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>none</p>
    <sp>none</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>69.169.224.12 (Amazon SES)</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>mercedes.franzoni.eu</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>franzoni.eu</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>t3mfs7y2mai3am32z7ordoghte2ff3lv</selector>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>amazonses.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>54ecsf3zk7z4mwxwwox7z7bg6e5gwjsz</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mailde.franzoni.eu</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

This is _dmarc.franzoni.eu DNS record:

```
_dmarc.franzoni.eu. 1800    IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:franzonieu-d@dmarc.report-uri.com; ruf=mailto:dmarcforensics@franzoni.eu; fo=1;"
```

I tested sending an e-mail to some DMARC analyzer tools (e.g. https://www.mail-tester.com/ ) and they all say my DMARC is all right, and I **never** get a forensic report even though I configured the ruf part. This makes debugging harder.

Any idea about why such thing is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW, it is very common today to comply with senders wishes for aggregate reports, yet not ever send forensics to untrusted destinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregate report is generated based on a time period and not whether there was a failure.

From [RFC 7489 7.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7489#section-7.2):

> Visibility comes in the form of daily (or more frequent) Mail
> Receiver-originated feedback reports that contain aggregate data on
> message streams relevant to the Domain Owner.  This information
> includes data about messages that passed DMARC authentication as well
> as those that did not.

A failure report is only generated when there is a failure.

From [RFC 7489 7.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7489#section-7.3)

> Failure reports are normally generated and sent almost immediately
> after the Mail Receiver detects a DMARC failure.  Rather than waiting
> for an aggregate report, these reports are useful for quickly
> notifying the Domain Owners when there is an authentication failure.
> Whether the failure is due to an infrastructure problem or the
> message is inauthentic, failure reports also provide more information
> about the failed message than is available in an aggregate report.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. So I never got a DMARC failure, that's the real reason for not getting forensics (=failure) reports. I had never looked directly at the RFC, only to other resources, including record generators, and the "forensics" vs "aggregate" distinction was quite blurred. I thought that ALL reports were failure reports, with the "aggregate" vs "forensics" being a way to discriminate. Lesson learned: always look at the original spec!